# How do I find a threshold to minimise some values? Relevant graph included

Tags: regression, predictive-models, scatterplot, threshold

I am trying to solve two sub problems based on this graph. My overarching problem is to predict the coordinates of a point, and give a confidence to the prediction. The y-axis is kind of arbitrary, with an absolute maximum value of 64, but no datapoint would ever plausibly reach that. You can interpret this graph as: the lower the error, the higher the confidence should be.

The two subproblems:

1. Find a **binary threshold for classification**. I want to find a confidence value (y-axis) that minimises the error (x-axis). I want to apply this threshold during testing to classify predictions as "confident" or "not confident". This seems simple - what methods can I apply to achieve this?
2. Transform the confidence (y-axis) value to a **continuous scale** to give a **probability of being confident**. This is difficult because what value should I consider 100% confident? From these samples the maximum confidence is 3, but the theoretical maximum is 4096. However, 3/4096 does not seem a good probability to reflect how confident the prediction is. What are some methods to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: How are "error" and "confidence" measured?  Ordinarily these concepts are linked through mathematical formulas and that can provide a good starting point to analyze these data.

Comment: @whuber "error" is measured in pixels. It is the distance between the predicted 2D coordinate point and the label 2D coordinate point. The predicted point is decided by 4096 voters, with the pixel with the most votes being selected. The  "confidence" is how many votes the selected pixel got. Therefore the theoretical maximum is 4096. However, this would never happen and we should consider a much lower number (e.g. 10) as very high confidence. For the second subproblem should I apply some log transform to the y-axis as part of the solution?